# Coldfusion sort query of queries on datetime field

Tags: sql-server, oracle, coldfusion

I have a coldfusion query of queries that I can't get to sort properly on datetime fields. One set of data comes from Oracle and the other from SQL server 2012. It looks like this:

```
<cfquery name="SQLNotes" datasource="sql">
    SELECT dateNoteDate AS dateContactTime, 
        strNote,
        customerID
    FROM Notes
    order by dateContactTime desc
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="OracleNotes" datasource="oracle">
 SELECT TO_DATE ( CONCAT( CONCAT(DATE, ' '), TIME ),  'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS')   AS "dateContactTime", 
 strNote,
 customerID
 FROM Notes
 order by dateContactTime desc
 </cfquery>


<cfquery name="AllNotes" dbtype="query">
 SELECT * FROM SQLNotes
 UNION
 SELECT * FROM OracleNotes
 ORDER BY dateContactTime desc
</cfquery>
```

It's just throwing the oracle notes in after the SQL server notes, not sorting them at all. 
I've tried different things, like casting the times to timestamps on the join and sorting by that.

I'm working with a sample of 11 rows, all of them are data type java.sql.Timestamp when I use queryName.dateContactTime[1].getClass().name.

Here are the times, in the order they are arranged when using `SELECT CAST(dateContactTime as TimeStamp) as ts order by ts desc`

04/25/16 02:49:14

04/25/16 02:47:21

04/25/16 01:25:24

04/25/16 01:21:41

04/25/16 10:49:45

04/25/16 10:48:44

04/25/16 10:42:56

04/25/16 10:26:34

04/25/16 10:26:29

04/25/16 01:49:50

04/25/16 01:08:22

Comment: (Edit) Yes, it should work if both columns are the same type, or are being cast to the same type. Just to be thorough A) Are you saying you tried casting both columns as a date in the QoQ, ie `CAST(Column AS Date) AS Alias` then ordering by the `Alias`, not the column name ? B) Did you try ordering by the column number, `ORDER BY 1 DESC` ? C) If neither works, what is a sample of the values and what are the reported data types of the two query columns, ie `queryName.dateContactTime[1].getClass().name`?

Comment: When you look at your data, do you see anything that would account for this?

Comment: Do what you have to do to create strings in yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss format in each set of query results and sort by that.

Comment: ORDER BY 1 DESC worked, but I don't really understand why.

Comment: I have seen that happens when you accidentally sort by a date *string* instead of a date/time column. Does not seem to be the case here, but ... something about how it is coercing the values for sorting is producing different results or values than expected. Hard to say exactly why without more details about the db queries. 1) What version of CF? 2) What are the data types of the columns in the original db queries?  3) Does the "OracleNotes" query already contain a column named "dateContactTime"?

Comment: Not related to your question, but the `order by` clauses in your db queries might be a waste of processing.

Comment: CF8, the sql column is datetime, and the oracle field is a date field and the time field is a 10 byte varchar (not my db, don't know why it was set up that way)